# Azure bot can't publish on skype

Tags: azure, botframework

I created a Bot on Azure Bot Framework and link it to Skype with out any issues. It works well when I add it to my contacts, but I would like to publish the bot to be able to add my bot to a Group. When i submit the request it returns:

> Your bot did not respond to our Ping request with a success code. Please verify your bot is running and responsive before Publishing your bot. The error received from your bot was: InternalServerError(500), Internal Server Error

Does anyone know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by your code not handling correctly system messages.

The following is an example of a method for handling system messages, that should be called when `message.Type == "Message"`:

```
private Message HandleSystemMessage(Message message)
{
    if (message.Type == "Ping")
    {
        Message reply = message.CreateReplyMessage();
        reply.Type = "Ping";
        return reply;
    }
    else if (message.Type == "DeleteUserData")
    {
        // Implement user deletion here
        // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
    }
    else if (message.Type == "BotAddedToConversation")
    {
    }
    else if (message.Type == "BotRemovedFromConversation")
    {
    }
    else if (message.Type == "UserAddedToConversation")
    {
    }
    else if (message.Type == UserRemovedFromConversation")
    {
    }
    else if (message.Type == "EndOfConversation")
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Update**

Instead of the message instance (depending if you are using .Net Core for example), try looking for an instance of **Activity**. You should see it as the parameter of your post method in your API controller.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this code should add here?    
public class SkypeBotBot : IBot

the temple that i have dont have any kind of "Message "

Comment: It should be in the controller

Comment: i used the template from [Bot Builder V4 SDK Template] and my code is look like link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

also under activityTypes class i dont see any type related to ping, only message,typing,contactRelationUpdate,conversationUpdate,messageReaction,handoff, and more..

Comment: Packge version .nuget\packages\microsoft.bot.schema\4.1.5\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Bot.Schema.dll

Comment: I found version 3 of the bot sample and ping is obsolete, see below messages.
[Obsolete("The ping activity is not used any more and can be removed from your code")]

Comment: Try returning an empty valid HTTP response when `activity.Type != ActivityTypes.Message` and see if your are still getting any errors. Without seeing the actual code you are using, I'd bet on something wrong in the system messages handling logic.

Comment: see reference i use the template from botframework 4 echo,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

I didnt change alot just the message format.

Comment: Try deploying one of the **bot.js** samples from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/01.console-echo/bot.js) to check if you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks works now.. :) just need to return if != message.